# Translation of custom attribute (defined for variables) from clang to llvm

Tags: variables, clang, llvm, custom-attribute

I need your guidance about a custom attribute. I have defined one for variables. It is accepted in the source code (without any warnings from clang), for example in following snippet.

```
 #define NEWATTR __attribute__((moviAttr(1)))

    int main()
    {
        NEWATTR volatile unsigned int a = 5;
        volatile unsigned int *p;
        p = &a;
        return (a+*p);
    }
```

and actually when I Dump the declaration, after adding the attribute in handleMoviAttr() function in SemaDeclAttr.cpp as shown in following snippet

```
D->addAttr(::new (S.Context)moviAttrAttr(Attr.getRange(), S.Context, Val, Attr.getAttributeSpellingListIndex()));
D->dump();
```

It is dumped by clang with following output

```
VarDecl 0x440c698 <file.c:6:17, line:10:32> col:32 a 'volatile unsigned int'
`-moviAttrAttr 0x440c6d0 <line:6:32, col:42> 1
```

HOWEVER, the attribute doesnt appear in IR of the program. IR is shown below.

```
*** IR Dump Before Pre-ISel Intrinsic Lowering ***; ModuleID = 'file.bc'
source_filename = "file.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:32:32-f64:64-i64:64-v128:64-v64:64-v32:32-v16:16-n8:16:32-S64"
target triple = "shave"

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = bitcast i32* %1 to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 4, i8* %2)
  store volatile i32 5, i32* %1, align 4
  %3 = load volatile i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = load volatile i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %5 = add i32 %4, %3
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 4, i8* %2)
  ret i32 %5
}

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nounwind
declare void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64, i8* nocapture) #1

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nounwind
declare void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64, i8* nocapture) #1

attributes #0 = { nounwind "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="myriad2.2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { argmemonly nounwind "target-cpu"="myriad2.2" }
```

Can someone help me please to solve the problem so that custom attribute also appears in the IR.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you emit the LLVM without optimization? (e.g. `clang -S -emit-llvm filename.c`)

Comment: clang attributes are totally separate from LLVM attributes. If you want it in the IR, you'll have to define the attribute on the LLVM side, and make changes in clang's `CodeGen` to somehow emit the LLVM attribute where you want it.

Comment: @FrankC. Yeah I used -S option, but it doesnt make any difference

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I am trying to modify EmitAutoVarAlloca() function in CGDecl.cpp but I dont know exactly what to do to make my custom attribute appear in IR, I want something like below
IR Without custom attribute: %1 = alloca i32, align 4
IR With custom attribute: %1 = alloca i32, align 4, Affinity

where affinity is undigned value provided my custom attribute.

Any ideas please?